# Java Maps of Lamda

Tags: java, карты, map, lambda, consumer

Требуется перевести оператор `switch` в лямбда-выражения.
Для этого нужно сделать `Map(у)` с возможными командами, и в зависимости от символа сделать нужную операцию.

Вот моя неработающая попытка:

```java
List<Operation> retValue2 = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Consumer<String>> activityMap = new HashMap<>();
Consumer<Integer> add = () -> {retValue2.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.ADD, +1));};
activityMap.put("+", add.accept());
Consumer<Integer> shift = () -> {retValue2.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.SHIFT, +1));};
activityMap.put(">", shift.accept());
```

Я пытался сделать это без Consumer, но я не понимаю, какой тип указать тогда в `Map`.

После нескольких попыток, решил, что нужно прийти к этому

`List<Operation> retValue2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, ТУТ НУЖНО ЧТО-то вставить> activityMap = new HashMap<>();
        activityMap.put("+", () -> retValue2.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.ADD, +1));
        activityMap.put(">", () -> retValue2.add(new Operation(Operation.Type.SHIFT, +1));`

Comment: Почему у вас лямбда ничего не принимает, если реализует `Consumer`? Зачем вы вызываете `accept` при добавлении лямбды в `activityMap`? Что такое `retValue2` и `Operation`?

Comment: и зачем вы пишете 2 разных элемента в мапу под одним и тем же ключом?

Comment: Это моя ошибка второй ключ был другой

Comment: По поводу косюмера, я просто не знаю, как запихнуть лямбду в мапу и решил взять консумер, но действительно забыл, что консумер должен принимать аргументы.
Я не знаю как реализовать это. @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: @WBLord объясните как можно подробнее, что именно должен делать ваш код.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я делаю интерпритатор для языка BrainFuck для этого в зависимости от команд ('+','-','.','>','<','.') я добавлял в Лист операции, которые нужно произвести. Раньше я это делал через оператор `switch` , мне сказали , что есть смысл переделать оператор `switch` на `map` в которой в зависимости от поступившей команды будет выполнять та или иная операция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется вам нужно использовать интерфейс Runnable.

Пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   List<String> retValue2 = new ArrayList<>();
   Map<String, Runnable> activityMap = new HashMap<>();
   activityMap.put("+", () -> retValue2.add("new Object()"));
   activityMap.put(">", () -> retValue2.add("124"));

   activityMap.forEach((key, value) -> value.run());

   System.out.println(retValue2.toString());
}
```

Вывод в консоли:
`[new Object(), 124]`